# Prepared PDO statement breaks code after setting variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have taken a login script from one of my other projects and was setting it up for my current one. After creating the database (it has no entrys) and uploading the files to the `FTP`, I went to the `INDEX` page but after I tried logging in once with incorrect details nothing happend, normally it should display a message saying 'incorrect credentials' but it didn't. I set up `echo` commands at various points within the code and managed to narrow down the error to one line. That line is setting a variable called `$sql` to a prepared `SELECT` statement, for some reason this is stopping the code as any `echo` commands placed after that will not run. Any ideas as to what is going on and how I can fix it? Or do you guys think it would be better to follow a more up [login system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ADiz3Dj_nQ&list=PLBOh8f9FoHHhRk0Fyus5MMeBsQ_qwlAzG)? That seems to include tokens which will also be helpful for security.

```
        // Confirm login
            echo "1";
            include("config.php");
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['pass'];
            if(isset($_POST) && $username != '' && $password != ''){
                echo "2".$username;
                $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM users WHERE username=?");
                echo "3";
                $sql->execute(array($username));
                if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
                while($result = $sql -> fetch()){
                    $pass = $result['password'];
                    $p_salt = $result['psalt'];
                    $id = $result['id'];
                }
                echo "3";
                $site_salt="salthashhere";
                $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
                if($pass == $salted_hash){
                    echo "5";
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $id;
                    header("Location:home.php");
                } else {
                     echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
                     echo "<a href='register.php'>Register Here</a>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Checked your error logs?

Comment: Could you please edit your code in such a way that it has a minimal verifiable example so that we can work on it easily without having to refactor your code?

Comment: Try getting PDO to throw exceptions.  `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` and check your error logs.

Comment: Is this same code you have in your file? You didn't have proper closing bracket for the given code. It missing `}`. I hope its copy/paste error otherwise this is the reason of misbehavior  of your code.

Comment: It might be a problem with your DB connection, do any other query work? Also you should look into password_hash and _verify to get a more modern password handling

Comment: Have you even got a `$dbh`?

Comment: Yes, it's in the config.php file that is included at the top. No other query works, I have tried running the register page. I am sure the login credentials for th config.php file are correct, do you want me to include the config file in my question as an edit?

Comment: Perhaps the pertinent bits with the username and password obfuscated.

Comment: @morgan did u check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you need to note `rowCount()` is not  guaranteed to give accurate results when used within the `SELECT` statement,  its normally used to returns the number of rows affected by the last **DELETE**, **INSERT**, or **UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

After select in your case you might need to fetch all your results as an array then use the [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) method to count the number of elements returned.

so try the following code :

```
<?php
// Confirm login
echo "1";
include("config.php");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
if (isset($_POST) && $username != '' && $password != '') {
    echo "2" . $username;
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM users WHERE username=?");
    echo "3";
    $sql->execute(array($username));
    $result = $sql->fetchall(); //fetch all results as array
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
            $pass   = $row['password'];
            $p_salt = $row['psalt'];
            $id     = $row['id'];

            echo "3";
            $site_salt   = "salthashhere";
            $salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password . $site_salt . $p_salt);
            if ($pass == $salted_hash) {
                echo "5";
                $_SESSION['user'] = $id;
                header("Location:home.php");
            } else {
                echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
                echo "<a href='register.php'>Register Here</a>";
            }
        }//end foreach

    } else {
        // account does not exist
        echo "<h2>account does not exist.</h2>";
        echo "<a href='register.php'>Register Here</a>";
    }
}
?>
```

> PS : You might wanna look and take the advantage of php builtin
>   password_hash() and password_verify() they are much more secured.